# Shopify liquid calling products with a limit/template

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am using [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) to power my eCommerce store, using the code below I am able to call all products within a specific collection to the page. I am trying to template the results so that every 3 products is wrapped in a list tag. Is this possible to make this happen by using my current code?

```
{% for product in collections.myCollection.products %} 
     <li>
         {{ product.title }} 
         <a href="{{product.url}}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'featured_image' }}" /></a>
         {{ product.price | money  }} 
     <li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible using cycle http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#cycle

```
{% for product in collections.myCollection.products %} 
 {% cycle '<li>', '', '' %}
     {{ product.title }} 
     <a href="{{product.url}}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'featured_image' }}" /></a>
     {{ product.price | money  }} 
 {% cycle '', '', '</li>' %}
{% endfor %}
```